# How Can I Import Category META Tags(Titles, Descriptions, Keywords) into DB Using MySQL Query?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, category, seo, meta-tags

Category META Tags(Titles, Descriptions, Keywords) Import not possible at the back end, how can I import into DB using MySQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute below query.

Assumption - Category already created. Also one more thing, you have to replace
`replace_this_with_category_id` with `entity_id` that will reference to `catalog_category_entity` table.

Adding values for 46 (see `eav_attribute`) - META title, 47 (see `eav_attribute`) for META keywords, 48 (see `eav_attribute`) for META DESCRIPTION

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`
(`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) 
VALUES 
('',3,46,0,'replace_this_with_category_id','META TITLE') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META TITLE',
('',3,46,0,'replace_this_with_category_id','META TITLE 1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META TITLE 1',
('',3,46,0,'replace_this_with_category_id','META TITLE 2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META TITLE 2';


INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_text`
(`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) 
VALUES 
('',3,47,0,'replace_this_with_category_id',`META KEYWORDS`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META KEYWORDS',
('',3,47,0,'replace_this_with_category_id',`META KEYWORDS2`)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META KEYWORDS2',
('',3,48,0,'replace_this_with_category_id',`META DESCR`)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META DESCR',
('',3,48,0,'replace_this_with_category_id',`META DESCR2`)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = 'replace_this_with_category_id',`value` = 'META DESCR2';
```

Just replace `replace_this_with_category_id` with `category_id`.

But make sure you take backup of your db first.

Comment: Is possible can I import bulk or keep writing query line by line for every category,,,, because in my site consists 100 's of category.

Comment: then you can use this - MageWorks  Extension http://www.magentoworks.net/import_categories.zip

Comment: after importing the file into the root folder, how can I use it, any formate?

Comment: in Backend, it will be under MageWorks menu, it will have two options export and import profiles

Comment: when i export i get error like :  Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\abcd\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\Product.php on line 875

Comment: $dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
                        
$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];

Comment: How can i solve the above error?

Comment: it works fine for me! in which action you are getting an error ?

Comment: Category exports

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61085/discussion-between-same-and-rathinam).

Comment: **There are ZERO guarantees regarding `attribute_id` values as they are just autoincrement foreign keys.**